# How to callout a REST web service using OAuth

Tags: apex, integration, webservices

Could anyone please assist me on how to call an external web service using OAUTH. Could you please show me the base template class I would use. I am given the following instructions on [Envisionme](https://api.envisionme.co.za/v1/docs#oauth). I already have an app on their side with the client_id and client_secret. Im just so frustrated becasue I have been searching documentation for the past two weeks and cant seem to get something to assist me :(. I wanna be able to then have a button on my contact page which will then call the class which will make the callout to that API and retrieve the response.

From what I have heard

Integration is the process which involves authentication. In general ways we use Oath2.0. 
Steps: 
1. We need to get code (authentication code )  from external application
2. Using this code we need to get access token
3. Now you are all set to hit any external api

What I need to know then is how to implement this. Could someone please give me a sample code which I could use to authenticate and start making my posts and gets. Such as the way I would using Ready API

[image]

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the "named credential" feature (new feature released in Spring 15).
http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=named_credentials_about.htm&language=en_US

With named credentials the Oauth2 authentication flow is handled automatically, you don't need to implement specific code for it.